Remove rounded corners in image preview when using Quick Look
Is there any way to remove the rounded corners of the image preview in Quick Look? Maybe some hidden preference?

I have to preview large amount of small images (assets for the applications I develop), and these rounded corners interfere a lot. For example compare the QuickLooked (left) with the actual image (right).
 
Thanks!

Does full-screen quicklook without the rounded corners... You just need to press Option+Command+y

Those images must be really small.  Another option would be to use the qlmanage command-line tool to generate thumbnails.

Someone else had this problem, and did quite a bit of reverse engineering to fix Apple's incompetence.
You can find the script here: https://github.com/rogual/fix-quicklook
Full warning, this involves disabling SIP and essentially modifying the code of a running process. I'd strongly recommend reading through the script before running it.
If you can, I'd highly suggest you send feedback to Apple encouraging them to add a setting to enable or disable this "feature"

Unbelievably nice write up python hot-patching the running processes when swizzling the methods failed  - https://foon.uk/fixing-quicklook/
